# Passing a date with JSON to .NET

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Here is my jQuery code:

```
function onSaveClicked()
{
    var message = 
    {
        MessageID: $("#MessageID").val() || 0,
        MessageDate: "\/Date(<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>)\/",
    };


    $.ajax({
       url: "<%= Url.Action("SaveMessage") %>",
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       data: $.toJSON(message),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function(result) {
            if (result && result.success)
            {
                //
            }
       }
   }); 
}
```

At first, I was just setting MessageDate to a string that was in a date format, but after some errors there, I did some research and it looks like I need to pass in the Ticks. But I get the following error:

**There was an error deserializing the object of type Models.MessageModel. The value '634185025866884281' cannot be parsed as the type 'DateTime'**

I've also tried:

```
MessageDate: "\\/Date(<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>)\\/",
```

but I get this error message:

**There was an error deserializing the object of type Models.MessageModel. DateTime content '/Date(634185027273624742)/' does not start with '/Date(' and end with ')/' as required for JSON.**

What do I need to do to get this working?

EDIT:
I'm using this to deserialize the JSON request:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(RootType);
        //RootType here is (Name = "MessageModel", FullName="Models.MessageModel")

        filterContext.ActionParameters["message"] = serializer.ReadObject(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);


    }
}
```

Comment: What is your `SaveMessage` action using to deserialize the JSON request?

Comment: I edited my original, it's showing above now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following function:

```
public static string FormatDate(DateTime dt)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DateTime));
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, dt);
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

And in your view:

```
var message = 
{
    MessageID: $("#MessageID").val() || 0,
    MessageDate: "/Date(<%= SomeClass.FormatDate(DateTime.Now) %>)/"
};
```

Comment: This gave me the following error:

There was an error deserializing the object of type Models.MessageModel. The value '/Date(1282924488721' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int64'

Comment: Could you post the JSON string that is passed in your ActionFilter? In your example the contents of `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream`.

Comment: I read the stream into a byte array, and then converted the byte array to a string. This is the result: "1233477101115115971031017368345848443484105116108101345834116101115116503444346810111599114105112116105111110345834116101115116105110103344434689711610183116971141163458344768971161014047689711610140495056505750565150515654504548524848414741473444346897116101691101003458344768971161014047689711610140495056505750565150515654514548524848414741473444348610511510598108101345810297108115101125"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What I did was use the following function to convert it to a number

```
private double GetUnixEpoch(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        var unixTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime() -
            new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        return unixTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
```

Then you can use that number in the constructor of the Javascript date object to create the date object.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I'd use that in my Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es5-discuss/2008-August/001666.html) gives this solution (modified) which you'd put on the client with JSON.stringify():

```
jsonData = JSON.stringify([new Date()], 
    function (k, v) { return this[k] instanceof Date ? '/Date(' + v + ')/' : v; });
```

Which works in the latest IE, Chrome, and Firefox for me.